# Detect if you're in the "Frontend Editor" mode in Visual Composer Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, visual-composer

Marketo forms tend to break the Wordpress Frontend Editor.

Now - my thoughts are to detect if I am just displaying the current page or I am in the frontend editor mode. If in frontend editor mode just to replace the normal form output with a placeholder (or just not display the JavaScript that breaks everything).

If somebody has any better suggestion - do not hestitate to!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I've dig in the core of WPBakery Visual Composer and came up with this solution:

```
function is_vc_build() {
    return function_exists( 'vc_is_inline' ) && vc_is_inline() ? true : false;
}
```

Hope it will help somebody in future as I spent lots of time on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one below:

```
function is_frontend_vc() {
    return function_exists( 'vc_is_inline' ) && vc_is_inline();
}
```

More easy to read and simple.